# How to connect a MySQL database hosted on cloud to Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-database-mysql

If I have a database that is hosted on cloud, hence publicly accessible, is it possibible to connect to it via Azure Integration-Runtime, or do I have to set up a self-hosted IR?

In the official documentation it's not clear, one [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#supported-data-stores-and-formats) indicating Azure IR not supported for MySQL, while digging through the detailed [connector's article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-mysql#linked-service-properties), it says the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

If your server  is publicly accessible, then you don’t need install a selfhosted IR. You could use ADF v2 UI to have a quick try. It provides the test connection function.

Seems the first article is out of date. Previously, it needs a MySQL driver to connect MySQL. But currently, ADF has a default driver now.

Comment: +1 Could you confirm the integration of the driver into the connector by using it or any other useful reference?

Comment: In the second doc you mentioned, it stated that “The Integration Runtime provides a built-in MySQL driver starting from version 3.7, therefore you don't need to manually install any driver.” As the azure IR will always be the lastest version, so it should include the built in driver.

Comment: It's supposed to be that way, I'm looking for someone that already went through all this stuff. I'll try it out, and we'll see. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,you need to install **Self-hosted IR** in order to access your Cloud hosted MySQL database.
As of today what I've tried, "Azure Integration-Runtime" does have that capability to connect cloud hosted MYSQL database.